# CSS format an element to go outside but still relevant to the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML elements.

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
    <div id="main">
        <div style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
        <div style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDiv">BLUE</div>  
    </div>
```

I would like to format the blue div in the following way:

1. Outside of the parent `main` div (should be displayed outside of the parent black box)
2. To be 10px right of the parent div

I tried to use position relative on the blue div, but it is relative to the whole screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Position the blue div absolutely and use relative positioning on the main div. Now you need to offset the blue div 100% off the left edge of the main div plus an extra 10px:

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <div style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
        <div class="outer" style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDiv">BLUE</div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: @Isaak — Wais is "absolutely" correct, but to understand why this works you need to understand that `absolute` is ... _relative_ ... "It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block." Read the descriptions of "relative" and "absolute" in the [MDN doc for position Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/position#values). I also think the [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) is helpful.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I realized that I did not understand the absolute position, I confused it with `fixed`. Thank you both.

Comment: @IsaakNewton actually `absolute` and `fixed` are almost the same. The only difference is that a fixed element stays in place when its parent element is scrolled.